# Unable to read text file from spring boot jar

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to read a file in the resources folder of my Spring boot console application but I am getting file not found exception.

here is my pom

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
```

And here is the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [9.txt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/abc/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/xyz/target/xyz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/9.txt
```

I opened the xyz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar file and the 9.txt is in BOOT-INF/classes folder.

Thanks,
-dj

Comment: how are you trying to read?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using ClassPathResource. ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(len + ".txt"); File file = resource.getFile();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File inside jar is not visible for spring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14876836/606662)

Answer (score 7):

It's Spring Boot, let's use ClassPathResource

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Value("9.txt")
    private ClassPathResource resource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        Files.lines(resource.getFile().toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:** Since [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) supports resolution as java.io.File if the class path resource resides in the file system, but not for resources in a JAR it's better to use this way

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Value("9.txt")
    private ClassPathResource resource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            bufferedReader.lines()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using ClassPathResource.      ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(len + ".txt");
File file = resource.getFile();

Answer (score 2):

this is working for me!

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + len + ".txt");
```

where as this didn't work

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(len + ".txt"); 
File file = resource.getFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot you can use `ResourceLoader` to read the file from Resource folder. It is an efficient way to read a file from the resource folder.
First Autowire ResourceLoader

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

then

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "9.txt");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `resource.getInputStream()` instead of `resource.getFile()` when loading a file from inside a jar file.